# Pintos - syscalls project 2

Tags: pintos

I am doing the Pintos project on the side to learn more about operating systems. I finished Project 1 and have started the second project. I already have setup stack verified and working (via hex_dump). Right now I am having issues getting the correct syscall arguments.

In user/syscall.c there are 4 assembly stubs(0 - 4 stubs) that the user syscall wrap.

```
 #define syscall3(NUMBER, ARG0, ARG1, ARG2)                      \
    ({                                                      \
      int retval;                                           \
      asm volatile                                          \
        ("pushl %[arg2]; pushl %[arg1]; pushl %[arg0]; "    \
         "pushl %[number]; int $0x30; addl $16, %%esp"      \
           : "=a" (retval)                                  \
           : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                         \
             [arg0] "g" (ARG0),                             \
             [arg1] "g" (ARG1),                             \
             [arg2] "g" (ARG2)                              \
           : "memory");                                     \
      retval;                                               \
    }) (this code is given to us)
```

I have some code inside of my syscall_handler that calls the correct function inside of the kernel.

```
static void syscall_handler (struct intr_frame *f) {

  uint32_t *args = f->esp;
  if (args[0] == SYS_WRITE) {
    f->eax = write(args);
  }
```

Inside of my write function I am printing out the FD and Size

```
int sysCallNumber = (int) args[0];
  int fd = (int) args[1];
  const char *buffer = (char *) args[2];
  unsigned size = (unsigned) args[3];

  printf("FD is %d\n", fd);
  printf("Size is %d\n", size);
```

Running 'echo hello stack overflow 1 22 333' will yield the result below. Note I added the notes in parentheses. () <-  Something is getting screwed up and FD is getting overridden with the size (including null terminator)

```
FD is 6    (hello)
Size is 6
FD is 6     (stack)
Size is 6
FD is 9    (overflow)
Size is 9
FD is 2    (1)
Size is 2
FD is 3    (22)
Size is 3
FD is 4    (333)
Size is 4
FD is 1   (this is from the printf("\n") in echo.c)
Size is 1
```

Ive ran this with GDB setting breakpoints and dumping frames and have not been able to figure it out. Has anyone encountered anything similar? If so how did you fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a bug recently in `user/syscall.c` that could be affecting you. Try applying this patch to `user/syscall.c`:

```
diff --git a/src/lib/user/syscall.c b/src/lib/user/syscall.c
index a9c5bc8..efeb38c 100644
--- a/src/lib/user/syscall.c
+++ b/src/lib/user/syscall.c
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
             ("pushl %[number]; int $0x30; addl $4, %%esp"       \
                : "=a" (retval)                                  \
                : [number] "i" (NUMBER)                          \
-               : "memory");                                     \
+               : "memory", "esp");                              \
           retval;                                               \
         })

@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@
                : "=a" (retval)                                           \
                : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                                  \
                  [arg0] "g" (ARG0)                                       \
-               : "memory");                                              \
+               : "memory", "esp");                                       \
           retval;                                                        \
         })

@@ -40,7 +40,7 @@
                : [number] "i" (NUMBER),                         \
                  [arg0] "g" (ARG0),                             \
                  [arg1] "g" (ARG1)                              \
-               : "memory");                                     \
+               : "memory", "esp");                              \
           retval;                                               \
         })

@@ -57,7 +57,7 @@
                  [arg0] "g" (ARG0),                             \
                  [arg1] "g" (ARG1),                             \
                  [arg2] "g" (ARG2)                              \
-               : "memory");                                     \
+               : "memory", "esp" );                             \
           retval;                                               \
         })
```

Here's the long story...

In the macro `syscall3` for example, the expected assembly code to be generated looks something like this

```
pushl ARG2
pushl ARG1
pushl ARG0
pushl NUMBER
int  $0x30
addl $16, %esp
```

This should work as long as the stack looks exactly as expected just push the interrupt instruction. Here is what the disassembled `write` function looks like in of the test programs (generated by `objdump -d pintos/src/userprog/build/tests/userprog/args-many`):

```
0804a1a5 <write>:
 804a1a5:       ff 74 24 0c             pushl  0xc(%esp)
 804a1a9:       ff 74 24 08             pushl  0x8(%esp)
 804a1ad:       ff 74 24 04             pushl  0x4(%esp)
 804a1b1:       6a 09                   push   $0x9
 804a1b3:       cd 30                   int    $0x30
 804a1b5:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 804a1b8:       c3                      ret
```

There is an enormous problem with these instructions. Because the arguments are being pushed onto the stack relative to the stack pointer `%esp`, the wrong arguments are pushed onto the stack! This is because `%esp` changes after every `pushl` instruction.

After doing some digging on the extended asm syntax for gcc, I think I found the right fix. The `%esp` register needs to be added to the Clobbers list in the extended asm instruction for each `syscall*`. This is because each `pushl` instruction modifies `%esp` indirectly, so we need to inform gcc of that modification so that it does not use `%esp` improperly in the generated instructions.

Comment: Really great response! Thank you so much, this saved me quite abit of time. I just finished up with virtual memory and am starting FS :)

Comment: No problem. I finally found the time to finish userprog, so I'm starting vm today.

Comment: Can you mark that my response answered your question? I'm new to stack exchange, but I think I get credit for providing good answers. =]